# How to read metadata in parquet file through a custom DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, metadata, parquet

My goal is to save metadata in a parquet file managed with pandas methods.

I defined a custom DataFrame to use a new attribute "alpha" (metadata). I show it in this fragment:

```py
class CustomDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    _metadata = ['alpha']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return CustomDataFrame
```

Then, I can use correctly this new attribute like `df.alpha = x`. The problem occurred when I save this CustomDataFrame by `df.to_parquet(filename)` and I try to read it as `df.read_parquet(filename)` because `df.alpha` is not defined.

However, if I do the same approach but using `df.to_pickle(filename)` and `df.read_pickle(filename)` the `alpha` attribute is saved successfully.

Any suggestions to use parquet format with metadata through a custom DataFrame? I want this because the memory is reduced to half in my files when I use parquet in comparision to pickle format.

Thanks!

Comment: I faced the same. I think I create a separate metadata information file beside the parquet file.